# Задержка выполнения кода

Tags: java

Есть вот такая часть кода

```
Proxy.getInstance().sendPacket(new CallBackHub_Packet_49(p.getName(), new Random().nextInt()), b -> {
        if (b.getId() == 50) {//Костыль
            SendCallBackHub_Packet_50 packet = (SendCallBackHub_Packet_50) b;
            p.sendMessage(Messages.PREFIX + Utils.message(rPlayer, Data.LOST_CONNECTIONS_SENDING_TO_HUB));
            e.setCancelServer(ProxyServer.getInstance().getServerInfo(packet.getServer()));
            p.setReconnectServer(ProxyServer.getInstance().getServerInfo(packet.getServer()));
            e.setCancelled(true);
            p.connect(ProxyServer.getInstance().getServerInfo(packet.getServer()));
        }
    }, 3000L, () -> p.sendMessage(Messages.PREFIX.toString() + Utils.message(rPlayer, Data.TIME_OUT)));
```

Я отправляю пакет от клиента серверу.
Проблема заключается в том что я должен ожидать получения ответа от сервера.
Как я могу застопорить клиента на то время пока не придет ответ от сервера?

Вариант с Thread.sleep() не подходит т.к все это делается в главном потоке и может очень сильно повлиять на всю систему.

Comment: Выносите в главный поток и там уже делайте отправку и делайте инструмент для ожидания ответа от сервера

Comment: Вот бы ещё знать, что у вас за классы используются, а то может какие-то из них позволяют устанавливать колбэки, возвращают футуры или дёргают мультиплексор при наступлении сетевого события.